Asymptotic behavior of Summation with Floor and Square Root function
I am trying to determine the asymptotic value of the following summation:
$$\sum_{a=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{x/2}\rfloor} \left\lfloor\sqrt{x-a^2}-a+1\right\rfloor$$
where $x$ is a real number.
The summation involves the floor function and square root function, which makes it challenging to analyze. I would like to know the steps to derive the asymptotic behavior of this sum, as well as any tight bounds on the order of growth $\Theta(x)$.
Any help in understanding the asymptotic properties of this summation would be greatly appreciated.

Is $\frac{\pi }{8}x + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt x )$ tight enough?
